# stdtr in python giving nan for p-value while doing t-test

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, p-value

I am using the following code to perform t-test:

```
def t_stat(na,abar,avar,nb,bbar,bvar):
     logger.info("T-test to be performed")
     logger.info("Set A count = %f mean = %f variance = %f" % (na,abar,avar))
     logger.info("Set B count = %f mean = %f variance = %f" % (nb,bbar,bvar))
     adof = na - 1
     bdof = nb - 1
     logger.info("Degrees of Freedom of a=%f" % adof)
     logger.info("Degrees of Freedom of b=%f" % bdof)
     tf = (abar - bbar) / np.sqrt(avar/na + bvar/nb)
     dof = (avar/na + bvar/nb)**2 / (avar**2/(na**2*adof) + bvar**2/(nb**2*bdof))
     logger.info("tf = %f, dof=%f"%(tf,dof))
     pf = 2*stdtr(dof, -np.abs(tf))
```

My output looks like :

```
     Set A count = 3547465.000000 mean = 0.001123 variance = 0.000369
     Set B count = 83759692.000000 mean = 0.001242 variance = 0.000424
     Degrees of Freedom of a=3547464.000000
     Degrees of Freedom of b=83759691.000000
     tf = -11.374250, dof=-2176568.362223
     formula:   t = -11.3743  p = nan
```

When I pass the same data as arrays and use the ttest_ind function, I get t = -11.374250  p = 0.000000.

Why is my function giving p as nan ? Afaik, I cannot treat nan as 0. How can I understand the exact difference between my t_stat and ttest_ind ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a glimpse of your data?

Comment: Hi @EliKorvigo, the data is an array of 0s and some floats between 0 to 1. A sample would look like : [0,0,0,.4,.24,0,0,0]. The mean, variance and count of each array are mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The degrees of freedom you are passing to the formula are negative.

```
In [6]:

import numpy as np
from scipy.special import stdtr
​
dof = -2176568
tf = -11.374250
2*stdtr(dof, -np.abs(tf))
Out[6]:
nan
```

If positive:

```
In [7]:

import numpy as np
from scipy.special import stdtr
​
dof = 2176568
tf = -11.374250
2*stdtr(dof, -np.abs(tf))
Out[7]:
5.6293517178917971e-30
```

I wonder how it has happened in your case, I've run your code trying to infer the input parameters:

```
In [13]:

def t_stat(na,abar,avar,nb,bbar,bvar):
     print("T-test to be performed")
     print("Set A count = %f mean = %f variance = %f" % (na,abar,avar))
     print("Set B count = %f mean = %f variance = %f" % (nb,bbar,bvar))
     adof = na - 1
     bdof = nb - 1
     print("Degrees of Freedom of a=%f" % adof)
     print("Degrees of Freedom of b=%f" % bdof)
     tf = (abar - bbar) / np.sqrt(avar/na + bvar/nb)
     dof = (avar/na + bvar/nb)**2 / (avar**2/(na**2*adof) + bvar**2/(nb**2*bdof))
     print("tf = %f, dof=%f"%(tf,dof))
     print(stdtr(dof, -np.abs(tf)))
In [14]:

t_stat(3547465, 0.001123, 0.000369, 83759692, 0.001242, 0.000424)
T-test to be performed
Set A count = 3547465.000000 mean = 0.001123 variance = 0.000369
Set B count = 83759692.000000 mean = 0.001242 variance = 0.000424
Degrees of Freedom of a=3547464.000000
Degrees of Freedom of b=83759691.000000
tf = -11.393950, dof=3900753.641275
2.2434573594e-30
```

Hope it helps you to find the problem anyway.